# Understanding $() (and for-loops) in bash

Tags: bash, command-substitution, for

I have a directory with git inside and `git branch` gives me the following output:

```
$ git branch
  branch1
* branch2
  master
```

The `*` marks the current branch. I would like to use this output in a script. So I loop over the lines like this:

```
$ for line in $(git branch); do echo "${line}"; done;
branch1
README.txt
branch2
master
```

Questions:

What happened to the `*` and why do I see `README.txt`[1]?

How can I loop over the lines returned by a normal `git branch` exactly as they are, with `*` and a space?

P.S.: I am on a Mac right now.

[1] (or any other file in the repository but this one only has one file "README.txt")

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, particularly [Why you don't read lines with "for"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 2):

When `$(git branch)` is expanded for the `for` loop to loop over it, it expands to the multi-line string

```
  branch1
* branch2
  master
```

Since the command substitution is unquoted, this is then split on spaces, tabs and newlines (by default) into the four words

```
branch1 * branch2 master
```

Each word then undergoes filename generation (globbing).  The second word, `*`, will be replaced by all (non-hidden) filenames in your current directory. This appears to be the name of one file only in your case, `README.txt`.

The final list that the loop will loop over is therefore

```
branch1 README.txt branch2 master
```

Instead, if you just want to output this in a script, use

```
git branch
```

without doing anything more.

If you want to save the output in a variable, use

```
branches=$( git branch )
```

Would you want to get the name of the *current* branch, then extract the branch whose name is preceded by a `*`:

```
curr_branch=$( git branch | awk '/^\*/ { print $2 }' )
```

Would you want to iterate over the output of `git branch`, use a `while` loop:

```
git branch |
while read -r star name; do
    if [ -z "$name" ]; then
        name=$star
        printf 'One branch is "%s"\n' "$name"
    else
        printf 'The current branch is "%s"\n' "$name"
    fi
done
```

You may also use `git branch --show-current` to get the name of the current branch directly.

Comment: `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` to show only current branch.

Comment: 1. Reason I do this I want to also do a $(git config branch.$line.description) and append it to the branch name, but I also want to keep the asterisk. 2. Thank you for this excellent write up!

Comment: Unless someone has tweaked options, `*` expands to all _non-hidden_ (i.e. non-dot) entries. Not all dirs have dotfiles other than the special . and .. but git'ed projects usually do.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks, I believe I have clarified that bit now.